# Best method of retrieving stats from multiple machines on local network

Tags: php, performance, sockets, monitoring, daemon

so im building a application that monitors rasp pi based devices on a network. the devices are running a program that provides a statistical array about the devices performance that we need to log, you can access this array via a socket connection to the device on a port. The network currently has 100 of these devices but will soon grow to several hundreds of devices on a single network.

Currently the application approached this by deploying a script via ssh2_scp to each of the devices, then the application running through the list of local ips and using stream_context_create && get_file_contents to ping the monitoring file on the remote devices. The monitoring file, then gets the stat array from the local machine then $_POSTS the data back to the app which stores this in the db.

This is not really ideal at the moment as im recording it takes around 1.45mins to cycle through the ip's check them (in a cheat fashion using a counter $i++ and while to cycle through a range of numbers rather then getting all the ips from the database which it will need to do when more ips are added and new locations) and retrieve the results and insert them into the db, with the cron job set to run the ping script every 2mins, as the number of devices increases this will  go over the 2minute periodical gap and start to get backlogs of data. The problem with this is there isn't really any method of checking weather the stream get contexts retrieves any data, or to check if that device is operating correctly from the data submitted back separately.

The server the application is sitting on is a massive beast so computational power on that side is not a problem, but on the rasp pi devices it's running id prefer it not to run any web server, at the most maybe the inbuilt php web server, but id prefer them not run any web server for security, as well as the fact their primary aim is not a web server.

I've been looking at running php daemon services from the command line, and wondering if its better suited to run the monitor application as a daemon services to establish socket connections directly to the machines to retrieve data back and forth. If i was to go down this road how would i approach it, would i create a daemon script for the monitored devices that listened on a port and returned the stat array through that, then the monitoring application daemon to establish connections to each devices and feed the data in?

Any advice on best method/most efficient way of doing this highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

> you can access this array via a socket connection to the device on a port.

I would simply create a script that accepted a range of hosts as a parameter, then hit this port with netcat. The script iterates through the specified hosts, and dumps results to the database. This alleviates any rasp pi side execution. For scalability, simply run multiple of the scripts, each with different ranges of devices simultaneously on your beastly server.